# Spring Cloud DataFlow Kubernetes Server does not work with valid docker URIs

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am in the process of upgrading a Spring Cloud DataFlow Kubernetes Server deployment from 1.2.2.RELEASE to 1.3.1.RELEASE, testing it with minikube.

After fixing invalid docker URIs (docker: to docker://) and successfully seeing apps registered in the shell, the deployment to the kubernetes server ultimately fails. With a simple stream:

```
mysource | myprocessor | rabbitsink
```

the Spring Boot sink app **does successfully deploy and start up** according to the pod's logs. Here's the successful registration of that app:

```
app register --name rabbitsink     --type sink       --uri docker://192.168.99.100:80/myrepo/rabbitsink:current
Successfully registered application 'sink:rabbitsink'
```

Despite this, the subsequent output from the dataflow shell is:

```
Command failed org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.DataFlowClientException: Invalid docker resource URI: docker:192.168.99.100:80/myrepo/rabbitsink:current
```

and none of the stream's other apps starts up.

Here's the stacktrace from the log:

```
2018-03-12 13:17:16.470  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 9393 (http)
2018-03-12 13:17:16.516  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.d.s.k.KubernetesDataFlowServer     : Started KubernetesDataFlowServer in 54.261 seconds (JVM running for 59.213)
2018-03-12 13:17:49.724  INFO 1 --- [nio-9393-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-03-12 13:17:53.604  INFO 1 --- [nio-9393-exec-1] .s.c.d.s.s.i.AppDeploymentRequestCreator : Creating resource with [docker://192.168.99.100:80/myrepo/rabbitsink:current] for application [rabbitsink]
2018-03-12 13:17:53.618  INFO 1 --- [nio-9393-exec-1] .s.c.d.s.s.i.AppDeploymentRequestCreator : Creating resource with [docker://192.168.99.100:80/myrepo/myprocessor:current] for application [myprocessor]
2018-03-12 13:17:53.624  INFO 1 --- [nio-9393-exec-1] .s.c.d.s.s.i.AppDeploymentRequestCreator : Creating resource with [docker://192.168.99.100:80/myrepo/mysource:current] for application [mysource]
2018-03-12 13:17:53.629  INFO 1 --- [nio-9393-exec-1] o.s.c.d.s.s.AppDeployerStreamDeployer    : Deploying application named [rabbitsink] as part of stream named [mystream] with resource URI [docker:192.168.99.100:80/myrepo/rabbitsink:current]
2018-03-12 13:17:54.833  INFO 1 --- [nio-9393-exec-1] o.s.c.d.s.k.DefaultContainerFactory      : Using Docker image: 192.168.99.100:80/myrepo/rabbitsink:current
2018-03-12 13:17:54.837  INFO 1 --- [nio-9393-exec-1] o.s.c.d.s.k.DefaultContainerFactory      : Using Docker entry point style: exec
2018-03-12 13:17:58.157  INFO 1 --- [nio-9393-exec-1] o.s.c.d.s.s.AppDeployerStreamDeployer    : Deploying application named [myprocessor] as part of stream named [mystream] with resource URI [docker:192.168.99.100:80/myrepo/myprocessor:current]
2018-03-12 13:17:58.935  INFO 1 --- [nio-9393-exec-1] o.s.c.d.s.k.DefaultContainerFactory      : Using Docker image: 192.168.99.100:80/myrepo/myprocessor:current
2018-03-12 13:17:58.935  INFO 1 --- [nio-9393-exec-1] o.s.c.d.s.k.DefaultContainerFactory      : Using Docker entry point style: exec
2018-03-12 13:18:04.523  INFO 1 --- [nio-9393-exec-1] o.s.c.d.s.s.AppDeployerStreamDeployer    : Deploying application named [mysource] as part of stream named [mystream] with resource URI [docker:192.168.99.100:80/myrepo/mysource:current]
2018-03-12 13:18:05.380  INFO 1 --- [nio-9393-exec-1] o.s.c.d.s.k.DefaultContainerFactory      : Using Docker image: 192.168.99.100:80/myrepo/mysource:current
2018-03-12 13:18:05.419  INFO 1 --- [nio-9393-exec-1] o.s.c.d.s.k.DefaultContainerFactory      : Using Docker entry point style: exec
2018-03-12 13:18:17.497 ERROR 1 --- [nio-9393-exec-1] o.s.c.d.s.c.RestControllerAdvice         : Caught exception while handling a request

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid docker resource URI: docker:192.168.99.100:80/myrepo/rabbitsink:current
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:92) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.registry.support.ResourceUtils.formatDockerResource(ResourceUtils.java:173) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-registry-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.registry.support.ResourceUtils.getResourceVersion(ResourceUtils.java:147) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-registry-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.stream.AppDeployerStreamDeployer.deployStream(AppDeployerStreamDeployer.java:141) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.AppDeployerStreamService.doDeployStream(AppDeployerStreamService.java:88) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.AbstractStreamService.deployStream(AbstractStreamService.java:85) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.controller.StreamDeploymentController.deploy(StreamDeploymentController.java:153) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111-internal]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111-internal]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111-internal]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in the 1.4.0.RELEASE version of Spring Cloud Dataflow and is working nicely with the 1.4.0.RELEASE versions of the local dataflow server, the kubernetes dataflow server and dataflow shell. It works with Spring Cloud Edgware.SR2 and Edgware.SR3.

Answer (score 0):

We have recently discussed a similar issue in [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow#2065](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/2065).

As highlighted in the [comment](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/2065#issuecomment-369104996), the Docker resource URIs are expected to be of a certain format starting from 1.3 release.

In your case, the Docker URI should have been:

> dataflow:>app register --name rabbitsink --type sink --uri docker:myrepo/rabbitsink:current

If the above format is not followed, the Shell would fail-fast with a validation message. The stream won't be deployed; no pods should show up for the apps either. Here's the validation message on my minikube environment.

> Command failed org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.DataFlowClientException: Invalid docker resource URI: docker:192.168.99.100:80/myrepo/rabbitsink:current

I'd recommend starting fresh. You could also use the [helm-chart](https://hub.kubeapps.com/charts/incubator/spring-cloud-data-flow) ([Docs for Minikube is in PR](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/pull/265)) to simplify the provisioning experience.

Comment: The problem I have is there's no resolution of docker artifacts without being able to specify 192.168.99.100:80 in the URI. I cannot make it work. helm is not an option in production so cannot form part of my test upgrade. Sadly, this is obviously not a straightforward and quick upgrade of versions anymore as previous releases of dataflow have been. I'll return to this if I have time in the months ahead.

Comment: Sorry to hear you've had issues with the artifact resolution in the past. FWIW, we resolve artifacts from Docker Hub without extra configuration. Perhaps there's something wrt private registry and that you're unable to get it working? Could you point me to the issue or more discussion on what you have tried and the stacktrace? We would be happy to help.

Comment: It'd be great if you can raise an issue with the details in [k8s-server backlog](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/issues). That way others with a similar problem might benefit from the discussion, and hopefully the resolution from us.

Comment: No resolution problems in the past with URIs like docker:192.168.99.100:80/myrepo/rabbitsink:current. It always worked. I wanted to upgrade to the 1.3.1.RELEASE version of dataflow, found that these URIs no longer work, mistakenly tried docker:// instead of docker:, described the recent behaviour in my first post and have tried with and without host and/or port. I set up minikube with a private registry (pushing to eval $(docker-machine env dev) and pulling into eval $(minikube docker-env)). It's worked flawlessly until now. I think I probably need to redo my minikube registry arch to cope.

Comment: That's because we _never_ validated it before! It was open-ended. It would fail to resolve at runtime!  We are providing richer support to perform CD with Skipper in 1.3, and to do that, we have to have a "consistent" app-registry in database. The validation provides the gatekeeping right now. Again, we would be happy to look into it to see why it is not working without the host, if you want to share more details in an issue.

Comment: Also, you mentioned you cannot use helm-chart in production, but you're on Minikube. Are you running Minikube in production then?

Comment: Production is full blown kubernetes. minikube is for my Mac. Everything is containerised with docker. In the near to medium term that's what we're staying with, but apparently there is a plan to move to openshift. There's one devops guy handling this (and other stuff), and then there's only me doing Spring Cloud with around 20 microservices. Not ideal, but resources are naturally stretched so I cannot do all that I should or want to. You say it should work with the host e.g. docker:192.168.99.100/myrepo/rabbitsink:current? I'll try to find some time to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug we need to address from what I can tell.  The test

```
    @Test
public void testDockerResourceProcessingSO() {
    DockerResource dockerResource = new DockerResource("192.168.99.100:80/myrepo/rabbitsink:current");
    assertThat(ResourceUtils.getResourceWithoutVersion(dockerResource)).isEqualTo("docker:192.168.99.100:80/myrepo/rabbitsink");
    assertThat(ResourceUtils.getResourceVersion(dockerResource)).isEqualTo("current");
}
```

Fails.  Due to this line of code

```
            String dockerResourceUri = dockerResource.getURI().toString();
        Assert.isTrue(StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf(dockerResourceUri, ":") == 2,
                "Invalid docker resource URI: " + dockerResourceUri)
```

and the dockerResourceUri is docker:192.168.99.100:80/myrepo/rabbitsink:current

There is also going to be another issue down the line if using skipper, in that the version needs to follow 'semver' format and 'current' isn't going to be valid.  We can look to better validate the docker format and get a fix in asap.

After we fix that, if you are using skipper, then skipper won't like 'current' as a version name, it needs to be a real version number.  Not yet sure if we can do anything to accommodate a 'dev workflow' without version numbers when the whole point of skipper was to manage version updates.  Maybe we need to allow 'current', 'latest', 'SNAPSHOT' as allowed versions and always redeploy those apps when and update is request.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll abandon the upgrade until the docker URI issue is fixed. I'm not using skipper in the short term but would highly recommend accommodating a dev workflow in all of this. If you've raised an issue about this can you point me to it please so I can track progress?